# Nesting click events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, coding-style, onclick

Sometimes my jQuery scripts I nest click events because I need my click event to operate on the element that the first click event created

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    //do something such as create an element
    $(selector).click(function(){
        //do something with the created element
    });
});
```

This feels like bad style. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you need to use event delegation here

Comment: Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or above, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', selector, function(){
  //do something
});
```

This will bind a click event to the selected element and automatically add it for new elements.

`off()` does the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

That *can* be a perfectly fine thing to do.

Alternately, you might look at event delegation. `on` (and the older `delegate`) provide that. Event delegation works by hooking the event (in your case, `click`) on an *ancestor* container element that already exists, but using a selector when hooking it up that will match the elements you're going to put in that container. When the event bubbles to the ancestor, jQuery compares the selectors against the elements it travelled through, and when something matches calls the event handler as though the handler had been attached directly to the element.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

As you can see, there are no rows in that table. But I can do this:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr", function() {
    alert("You clicked row #" + $(this).index());
});
```

...and then add rows as I like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    $("#myTable tbody").append("<tr><td>Hi there, click me</td></tr>");
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ihunir/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ihunir/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like delegate method of jQuery

Ex:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>delegate demo</title>
<style>
p {
background: yellow;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 5px;
}
p.over {
background: #ccc;
}
span {
color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click me!</p>
<span></span>
<script>
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() {
$( this ).after( "<p>Another paragraph!</p>" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```